# Equivalent python setup from OSX to Windows 10

Tags: python

I have my OSX machine configured to use python (running python3 from brew, so it won't upset the standard 2.7 included with OSX); and now I would like to use my windows machine too.

Although the main issue is that Windows does not have a terminal; so I am not sure how do I port my setup there. I use 3rd party libraries and packages, so it is not just a matter to install python3.

On OSX I would call `pip` to install packages, or use brew for what is not available via pip. On Windows I did install `git`, which add a minimal unix terminal environment, and then installed python 3 via regular windows installer.

At this point, I am not clear about how to proceed correctly. Can I just use pip from the git bash terminal window and install packages like I do on OSX? Also Windows does not have `brew`, so how do I get these packages and install them? This is my first attempt at python on windows, since I have been working mostly on OSX with python, and with C# on Windows.

Comment: Windows _does_ have a terminal. The builtin terminal is `cmd.exe`, which is also somewhat confusingly the shell, and it's a very different shell from bash—but it works just fine for running `pip` and your own command-line Python scripts. (However, you usually want to use `py -m pip` and `py` instead of `pip3` and `python3`.) And there are multiple ways to get bash on Windows as well (including the one that comes with the git-bash installer) if you want.

Comment: There are also a number of third-party package managers for Window that are roughly equivalent to `brew` or `macports` on Mac—Chocolatey, Scoop, and probably more that I don't know because I'm a couple years out of the loop. But even more Python packages come with pre-compiled wheels on Windows than on Mac, often including whatever C libraries they need, so you may not even need a package manager.

Comment: Finally: the most important thing is making sure you have the same site-packages installed. The best way to do this is (1) use `virtualenv`, and (2) use a `requirements.txt` file to pip all your dependencies at once. (The two combine nicely—you can test the requirements file against a brand-new virtualenv on your Mac, before trying to install it on a Windows virtualenv.)

Comment: Thanks a lot; so I can use windows shell as if I was on terminal. I never used it since it was more natural for me to use unix commands (which is why I did install git with the terminal emulator). I will try also virtualenv; never felt the need to use it but it seems that this is a good case for trying it

Comment: Well, a lot of details are different. For example, if you want to set command-line variables, you have to know that the closest thing to bash `export` in cmd is `SET`, and that it's only kind of similar, not identical, and so on. So, if you're doing anything complicated, you probably want to use bash. But for basic stuff like installing packages and running your own scripts, you can live with cmd. And for Windows-specific stuff like using Chocolatey, you might _have_ to. (Or you can learn PowerShell, which is a lot better than cmd, but even _more_ different from bash…)